# Read ApplicationInsights trace events with Insights library

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-application-insights

Writing trace events to Applications Insights is extremely easy on any platform. For example, in C# under dotnet core it is:

```
Client.InstrumentationKey = InstrumentationKey;
Client.TrackTrace("Test Trace from DotNet Console App.");
```

But reading that data back appears to have no such simple API, at least via NuGet.

I have seen the documentation for Kusto:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/kusto/api/netfx/about-kusto-ingest

But the closest I've come to simply and easily reading trace events is by reading the documentation for the [API Explorer](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/events) and converting that into dotnet core C#:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler {}))
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", ApiKey);

    var response = client.GetAsync(InsightsUrl).Result;

    var succ = response.IsSuccessStatusCode;

    var body = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    var path = $@"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}..\..\..\Insights.json";
    File.WriteAllText(path, body);
}
```

What is a comparably easy method to use for reading Insights trace (etc) events without having to build a web client?

Comment: What is the question here? Are you just looking for opinions on your code?

Comment: Question edited. I make the comparison between the ease-of-use of logging to Insights and the difficulty (relatively) of reading that data back because the relative different is significant, IMHO. I would like to know if there is a 1 or 2 line method to read data from Insights, just as there is a 1 or 2 line method to write it.

Comment: Web api is the way to go. There is currently no other option to read it using c#. If you are only interest in the data from the source that is actually sending it you have more options.

Comment: I should point out that the usage I had in mind has been superseded by report generation directly out of Azure, specifically Metrics. I would recommend this be the first port of call for anyone looking to do the same thing (though it was fun and interesting to code against the RESTful API for trace events!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, no other simple ways like 1 or 2 line method for reading the trace(and other telemetry data) back.

As of now, the [web api](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/quickstart) you used is the best way to achieve that.